# Remote collaboration for my RoR project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, repository, dropbox, rubymine, collaboration

I have a Ruby on Rails project in my local machine and I use the RubyMine IDE to change the related source code.

Recently, I found a (remote) collaborator for my project, and I would like to share my code with him so that we can work on it. However, I am not sure on how to proceed to make it possible, and also have some troubles e.g. on how to properly manage Git version control with my collaborator.

Since we want our project to be private and cannot use paid services (e.g. GitHub), I thought about using Dropbox as a repository so that both me and my collaborator can change the source code but keeping advantage of using git version control features.

Have you some advice about? Is Dropbox is the right choice? Can you point me out to good resources?

Comment: Github is free for public projects. Using dropbox seems like a PITA since it tends to lock files and does not work with source control.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are saying GitHub is paid because you need it to be private, you can use [bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bitbucket instead of Git. On Bitbucket there are 5 private repository are free...